# TypeError: fit() takes exactly 2 positional arguments (1 given) using python surprise library

Tags: python-3.x

I can use svd this way

```
def predict(data, uid, iid):

    trainset = data.build_full_trainset()
    # Set the algorithms to predict
    algo = SVD()
    algo.fit(trainset)
    pred = algo.predict(uid, iid)
    print(pred.est)
```

but if I try to use it on a for loop

```
def predict(data, uid, iid):

    trainset = data.build_full_trainset()

    algorithms = (SVD, KNNBasic, KNNWithMeans, NormalPredictor)


    for a in algorithms:
        a.fit(trainset)
        pred = a.predict(uid, iid)
        print(pred.est)
        print(pred)
```

I get this error

```
line 30, in predict
    a.fit(trainset)
  File "surprise/prediction_algorithms/matrix_factorization.pyx", line 152, in surprise.prediction_algorithms.matrix_factorization.SVD.fit
TypeError: fit() takes exactly 2 positional arguments (1 given)
```

I'm totally new on python but I think I'm calling the fit method in the same way both codes ,why the first works and the the second doesn't works??

Comment: Outside the loop if I use  `algo = KNNBasic() algo.fit(trainset)` works ,fit works with the 4 method but  only outside the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the instance of a SVD class, like you did in the first example. If you look at the code of the [fit()](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/decomposition/truncated_svd.py#L127) function you'll see it takes 2 positional arguments - `self` and `X`. The `y` argument is not a positional argument as it has a default values.

```
def fit(self, X, y=None):
```

The first parameter of methods - `self` - is the instance the method is called on and it's passed under the hood. If you don't create an instance of a class `SVD` then the `self` argument is missing and you need to pass it on your own.

To answer your question, let's create the instance of a class before calling `fit()` on it. And a second thing, note that the declarations of the `fit()` methods for `SVD`, `KNNBasic`, `KNNWithMeans`, `NormalPredictor` classes may differ.